# Accessing local directories from the Jupyter Notebook in Docker

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to access my desktop from my Jupyter Notebook and it seems that the file structure is different. I'm running the notebook on a mac, and on a docker container.

I'm running the docker container with:

```
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint "/run.sh" -p 8888:8888 -v `pwd`:/src udacity/carnd-term1-starter-kit
```

And running:

```
import os

ROOT = os.path.abspath("/")
directories = os.listdir(ROOT)
for dir in directories:
    print(dir)
```

I get:

```
/src
proc
dev
media
sys
srv
lib
home
mnt
root
var
tmp
etc
usr
boot
opt
bin
run
lib64
sbin
.dockerenv
run.sh
src
environment.yml
```

Whereas on my mac I get:

```
Applications
Library
Network
System
Users
Volumes
anaconda3
bin
cores
dev
etc
home
miniconda3
net
opt
private
sbin
tmp
usr
var
```

Any ideas how I can access my mac's directories from the Jupyter Notebook in Docker?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So the way I solved this was to add `--network="bridge"` in the `docker run` command [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach).

This enabled me to access my local directories under the `/src` directory in Jupyter.